# How do I install g++ on MacOS X?

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I want to compile C++ code on MacOS X, using the g++ compiler. How do I install it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's the compiler that comes with Apple's XCode tools package.  They've hacked on it a little, but basically it's just g++.

You can download XCode for free (well, mostly, you do have to sign up to become an ADC member, but that's free too) here: http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html

**Edit 2013-01-25:** This answer was correct in 2010. It needs an update.

While XCode tools still has a command-line C++ compiler, In recent versions of OS X (I think 10.7 and later) have switched to [clang/llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/) (mostly because Apple wants all the benefits of Open Source without having to contribute back and clang is BSD licensed). Secondly, I think all you have to do to install XCode is to download it from the App store. I'm pretty sure it's free there.

So, in order to get g++ you'll have to use something like [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (seemingly the current way to install Open Source software on the Mac (though [homebrew has a lot of caveats surrounding installing gcc using it](https://docs.brew.sh/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers#custom-gcc-and-cross-compilers))), [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) (basically Debian's apt system for OS X/Darwin), or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (Basically, OpenBSDs ports system for OS X/Darwin) to get it.

Fink definitely has the right packages. On 2016-12-26, it had [gcc 5](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gcc5) and [gcc 6](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/gcc6) packages.

I'm less familiar with how MacPorts works, though some initial cursory investigation indicates they have the relevant packages as well.

Comment: From what I see XCode is not free unless you enroll to iPhone or Mac Development programs, which is quite expensive unless you don't really plan to actually do that development. Do you guys know any free way to install g++ only? Thanks

Comment: @lyuba: It's possible to register as a developer for free. At least, last I checked it was. And then it's possible to download for free.

Comment: I guess that no anymore, now it's around $4.99. My friend who writes for the iPhone has also confirmed that. For him it's free since he is on the developer program. I've solved my case with installing XCode 3.

Comment: don't forget that the newest version requires you to download the command-line tools in the XCode preferences and to also probably run "xcode-select" to setup symlinks.

Comment: @Pestilence - Also, Apple is moving away from gcc/g++ and moving towards LLVM.

Comment: @Pestilence - I'm not sure if xcode-select is required, I think it happens automatically.

Comment: It was for things like MacPorts to work correctly. Perhaps they've fixed it.

Comment: The creator and primary author of LLVM, Chris Lattner, works at Apple, so I don't know what you are saying about that "not wanting to contribute" jab. Apple isn't very transparent (like, at all), but that doesn't mean they don't contribute.

Comment: this is now a non-answer, g++ is an alias for clang

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ - Non-answer is a bit harsh, but it is certainly obsolete.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ - Yes. Don't you just download it from the App store now? Do you know if you have to give them some kind of indication you're a developer before they'll let you download it?

Comment: @Omnifarious `$ g++` - `clang: error: no input files`  - lldb is bugged, I need to use gdb, but gdb works only well with g++

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ - Ahh, yes. The original question wasn't about how to get a command line C++ compiler, it was about how to get g++ specifically. I've updated it now, though my update isn't hugely detailed.

Answer (score 10):

Installing XCode requires:

- Enrolling on the Apple website (not fun)
- Downloading a 4.7G installer

To install g++ ****WITHOUT**** having to download the MASSIVE 4.7G xCode install, try this package:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

The DMG files linked on that page are ~270M and much quicker to install.  This was perfect for me, getting homebrew up and running with a minimum of hassle.

The github project itself is basically a script that repackages just the critical chunks of xCode for distribution. In order to run that script and build the DMG files, you'd need to already have an XCode install, which would kind of defeat the point, so the pre-built DMG files are hosted on the project page.

Answer (score 6):

Type g++(or make) on terminal.

This will prompt for you to install the developer tools, if they are missing.

Also the size will be very less when compared to xcode

Answer (score 4):

Download Xcode, which is free with an ADC online membership (also free):

http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it on the newer mac chips and how to switch from clang(default) to g++

- Install g++ through home-brew.
- Check out the version you just installed, probably 12th or higher
- You can make a symbolic link from g++-12 to g++

In order to do it, just type in your terminal:

```
sudo ln -s $(which g++-12) /usr/local/bin/g++.
```

Now open a new terminal and check your version again and you should see g++ instead of clang

```
g++ --version
```

Answer (score 1):

xcode is now available for free from the app store.  Just "buy it" (for free) and it will download.  To get the command line tools go into preferences/downloads and "install command line compiler tools".

Instead of gcc you are using clang, but it works the same.