# Are there any free C++ compilers for MacOSX?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-construction, c++11

Is there any free C++ compilers to install in Mac OS (apple machine)

please ..tell me the links to download & procedure to INSTALL.Since iam an new use for mac OS

Comment: Almost a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122425/how-do-i-install-g-on-macos-x

Comment: What does this have to do with C++0x?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The native compilers are gcc and llvm which are part of the XCode environment.

While the compilers are free, the latest IDE is not but can be bought from the app store for <strike>something like $5.99</strike> $4.99.

If you don't need the latest version, a 3.x version of XCode, including gcc, should be on your OSX DVD. Just install it from there.

Comment: [It's $4.99](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id422352214?mt=12)

Comment: @Rup - Thanks. I bought it in my local currency and probably payed a higher VAT.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

[g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and a host of others. Just google. Isn't [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/)  available on your machine ?

Comment: I removed Xcode as I needed space and I don't use Xcode so wanted to get rid of those GBs.

Answer (score 3):

I am hapily using gcc.4.6.1 prerelease from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gcc). You'll need to [install macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) first. Then,

sudo port install gcc46

This will most likely install is in `opt/local/bin`, and the executable will be `/opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.6` and `/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.6. One advantage is that it doesn't overwrite your system gcc. To use it as default (for C++) , I have set an alias in my login script:

```
alias g++='g++-mp-4.6 -std=c++0x'
```

The last option is to have access to gcc 4.6 implementation of c++0x, although beware that it may be incomplete or may change in the future when c++ 2011 comes out.

Comment: +1 for mentioning MacPorts. Another option is fink; homebrew is yet another. At least one of these three is an absolute essential. Which one is best? The one you aren't using, of course. Or if you have all three, the one that is currently last in your search path 'cause you got POed at that particular package three months ago.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode, including compilers, is on your Mac OS X installation DVD. You can install it from the DVD, or else download it for free from Apple's [developer website](http://developer.apple.com/) or for a small fee (where I live it is about € 5) from the OS X app store.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a fully integrated IDE - [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) - for a very low price (nearly free) with its operating system (or as download). Until recently it was free.

[clang](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), [gcc](http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html) and some other compilers are available for Mac OSX. Its foundations in the UNIX world makes it quite easy to find a lot of OSS compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an IDE, you can't beat [Xcode](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~mcs171/Wi07/extras/xCode_Instructions/index.html) on Mac.

Otherwise, g++, or you could look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C.2B.2B_compilers).