# How to find out which cpp compiler is used on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos

Im using CLion on MacOS, compiler was installed before. I would know what compiler is used for c++. Is exist some kind of command for echo it in terminal?

Comment: As far as i know, the name, version, etc. of the compiler is not discernible from looking at the the executable file. The `clang` compiler comes with MacOS; do `clang --version`.

Comment: got it, thanks! command: cc --version

Comment: If my comment was useful, please upvote it by clicking on the little triangle next just left of it in the margin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any free C++ compilers for MacOSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438792/are-there-any-free-c-compilers-for-macosx)

Answer (score -1):

I've used `g++` to compile my cpp files in OSX.