# Eclipse with CDT on Mac

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

I've been trying to get Eclipse with CDT working on my Mac for a while now. Everything I've searched for talks about Windows and I'm officially stuck.

The errors I get are:

`Program "g++" not found in PATH`

`Program "gcc" not found in PATH`

and a few more that seem to stem from a problem with my PATH. I checked gcc, g++, make, and gmake in terminal using --version and they're all installed. Eclipse CDT is supposed to detect where to look for PATH variables and I can't figure out where I would change it or how to change it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** The original problem was fixed. My PATH variable in eclipse was empty for some reason so I had to add locations like /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin. Now I get the error that "Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved."

**Edit 2:** I was able to get everything working by uninstalling everything and reinstalling Eclipse Indigo with CDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no C / C++ compiler installed.

Options are:

1. Install gcc from here (best): https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer
2. Install all of Xcode (1 gig install)
3. Install command line tools only from Xcode https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Once installed make sure you can call the compiler from the command line (type gcc) if it does not work the compiler has not been added to the environment path variable.

Some extra help:
[How do I install g++ on MacOS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122425/how-do-i-install-g-on-macos-x)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial that shows all the necessary steps for linux. I think it should be quite similar.

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

Maybe you'll have to add the path to gcc to your PATH variable if none of this is helping. It should work like this:

Open up .bash_profile in a text editor. (If you're using TextEdit, you can do this at the command line with "open -a /Applications/TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile".) Add the line:

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

to the file. Save the file and open up a new terminal, then type "echo $PATH" to see if it worked correctly.

**EDIT:** Someone else had the exact same output as you and managed to fix it by replacing his Eclipse version with an older one. You may try to use Helios instead of Indigo or Juno. This is just a temporary solution until something better comes up (in case it really works). I actually prefer Indigo and Helios over Juno, to be honest. In case you have any worries - Helios is the release from 2010 and still pretty good.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the help. When I try to open .bash_profile via the Terminal, I get an error saying "The file ...bash_profile does not exist.

Comment: I created the .bash_profile file and added your export line to it. When I open Eclipse I still get the errors I used to.

Comment: You need to find it. You can't just create another one somewhere else. This won't work. Do you have the file /etc/environment ?

Comment: I was able to get rid of my original error. I was making a stupid mistake and my PATH variable wasn't pointing to the right place in Eclipse. Now the errors I get are "Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved."

Comment: I was able to get it working by uninstalling everything, including gcc and g++, and reinstalling Indigo with CDT. It all works now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For cout - do you have #include ? Note that cout is a part of std namespace - you need to either qualify it or use "using" directive.

Comment: Yep, I have all of the #includes I need and using namespace std. I also created a new Hello World project that is usually able to just be compiled and ran but I still get that Symbols are not resolved.

Comment: Is it able to find that header (e.g. can you cmd+click on its name)? Looks like you env might be messed up big time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter `~/.bash_profile`, see below for the procedure:

1. open terminal window
2. send cmd `echo $PATH`, then copy the -bash output
3. send cmd `touch ~/.bash_profile`
4. send cmd `open -a TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile`
5. bash_profile will be opened, an empty text file, it means, it the first time it is created.
6. write in the empty bash_profile: `PATH='paste the copied items from echo $PATH cmd a while a back'`
7. save it and reopen the terminal, verify the echo `$PATH` again.
8. Restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is

in preference-> `c/c++ -> build->enviroment` add `PATH= /usr/local/bin`

hope it is fine for you.