# WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations

Tags: python, python-3.x, g++, anaconda, theano

I am trying to run theano library code My setup is  macos sierra x64 and pycharm with anaconda pacakges.

I installed theano :  pip install theano and it installed successfully but when i am trying to run code its giving this error :

```
   WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be
 unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and
 will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely
 degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
```

Then i searched on internet and found i have to install `conda install mingw libpython` to work with theano so i tried but later i found those two module  `mingw and libpython` are only for win platform.

What should i do now?

Comment: Take a look at the instructions to install g++ on Mac [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122425/how-do-i-install-g-on-macos-x).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the anaconda distribution, it would be easiest to install theano using the `conda` package manager.

**Note**: macos comes with a Python interpreter (2.7, I think) out of the box. Are you sure that `pip` installed theano in the *anaconda* python?