# C++ compiler on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, g++

How can I install the C++ compiler on Mac? I need compiler like MinGW on Windows or G++ on Ubuntu, not Clang, that's important.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: you'll be looking for homebrew

Comment: @BoPersson There is some difference between MinGW and Clang, cause the first one can compile with the bits/stdc++.h library, understand braced lists, etc, the second one cannot

Comment: Never use "bits/stdc++.h ". Whoever taught you this should turn in his C++ card. Clang of course can "use braced lists", whatever that means. You need to install the latest version.

Comment: I must be missing something, why is clang not good enough (my personal view, possibly slightly tainted, is that clang is a BETTER compiler than gcc. Not MUCH better, but certainly not significantly inferior)

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple three-step process:

1. Install Xcode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122428/1120273).
2. Having a C and C++ compiler, now compile the preconditions for the installation of [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/).
3. Compile and install [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) according to the instructions for gcc. It is a while since I last compiled gcc with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/): you may need to first compile an older release of gcc and use that to compile the actual version of gcc you want.