# I came across many Fatal error: No such file or directory when trying to use g++ to run a cpp file

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, terminal, g++

I'm a freshman who is getting used to g++ on Mac. I've installed GCC via Brew.sh but when I tried to run a cpp file, there was an error raising:

**fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory**

I've surfed the net to find out the solution. I've tried many ways they told but it couldn't help.

Then, I copied the wchar.h file from the Internet and paste it into my device. When I run again, there was a new error.

**fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory**

I also downloaded features.h, but then my computer required bits/predefs.h, long-double.h and so on. The more files I added in, the more other files my computer required me.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem? Thanks a lot for reading my topic.

Comment: are you sure you are in the correct directory?

Comment: Could you talk more clearly? I'm sorry I'm just trying to get familiar with g++

Comment: All I wanted to say was, check your path. See if you are running the command at the wrong path. This is not a `g++` familiarity thing, but more of a terminal familiarity thing

Comment: Installing a compiler should be automatic, and compilation should just work right out-of-the-box, i.e. the compiler installation steps should be smart enough to install what is necessary.  You having to download this and that and possibly do more damage to an installation isn't the way to solve something like this.

Comment: I would also think that the installation is not complete. Please let someone experienced take a look at your installation to find out which packages are missing.

Comment: BTW, what *exactly* did you install?

Comment: I think you should start with something easy, An IDE perhaps? I recommend VS or Eclipse...

Comment: I also tried to reinstall gcc but it couldn't help. I follow this video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z-fCNNqfEg

Comment: uh huh, gcc and g++ are **different**

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122425/how-do-i-install-g-on-macos-x)

Comment: I'm using XCode now. But it's hard when my friends and I do some projects cause they use Windows. So we decided to code on an cpp file and use g++ to run it

Comment: How will that help? What you probably want is to have a standard IDE. Check out which ones are available on Windows and Mac. (Hint, if you are a beginner, I recommend giving Ubuntu a try)

Comment: Yay I know GCC and g++ is different but in that video, he also guide how to install g++ using Homebrew

Comment: I will consider your suggestion. Thanks a lot. But anyone has any link that guide to install g++ on mac step by step? Because some of you said that the installation might not be completed.

Comment: You probably need to install xcode command line tools. Do a google on that to see how.